# Как увеличить время действия экрана загрузки уровня?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Есть скрипт и он работает когда грузится уровень, но грузится так быстро, что проигрывается всего 1 кадр. Как сделать так чтобы грузился уровень хотя бы секунд 5???
вот мой код

```
public void NextLvl()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        player.enabled = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        StartCoroutine(LoadingScreen());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadingScreen()
    {
        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        while (!operation.isDone)
        {
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / .9f);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если уровень грузится быстро, то зачем нужен экран загрузки, если его цель - не дать подумать пользователю, что игра зависла.

Comment: Для красоты между переходами уровней, так лучше выглядит. Типо персонаж переходит из зоны в зону

Comment: Может сделаете что-то типа затухания. Ведь если уровень быстро грузится это идеальный вариант. Есть плавный переход и всё быстро. Если этого вам не хватит сделайте анимацию, что персонаж выбегает на уровень.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но как?